# AngularJS - UI Router stateChangeSuccess event not firing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I am using [UI Router](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router) in my angular app. I am trying to integrate `state change` events, but they are not firing on state change. Everything else is working fine and there is no error in console. I came across following similar questions, but none of the solution worked for me:

[$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess) or $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess) does not work when using ui-router(AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470464/rootscope-onroutechangesuccess-or-rootscope-onstatechangesuccess-doe)

[angular + ui-router: $stateChangeSuccess triggered on state b but not on a.b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26488088/angular-ui-router-statechangesuccess-triggered-on-state-b-but-not-on-a-b)

Following is my Angular code:

```
(function() {

    angular.module("bootdemo", [
        "ngResource",       
        "ui.router",
        "bootdemo.core",
        "bootdemo.index"        
    ])
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location, $state, $stateParams) {

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
            alert("root change success");
        })

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){ 
            alert("root change start");
        })

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ 
            alert("root change error");
        })
    })
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: "/",
                templateUrl: '/index/templates/welcome.html',
                controller: 'IndexController as vm' 
            })
            .state('login', {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: '/index/templates/login.html',
                controller: 'LoginController as ctrl'   
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: "/home",
                templateUrl: '/index/templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeController as ctrl'    
        })
    });



}());
```

Left with no clue. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I had problem with the "alpha" version, if you use this one, downgrade

Comment: Bang On! I had the same issue. Thanks @ThomasP1988

Answer (score 39):

StateChange events has been deprecated for `ui.router >= 1.0`

for the new `ui.router` use the following

StateChangeSuccess

```
$transitions.onSuccess({}, function() {
  console.log("statechange success");
});
```

StateChangeStart

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(trans) {
 console.log("statechange start");
});
```

Check this [migration guide](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0) for more information

Answer (score 14):

If you are using the new ui-router (v1.0.0), the `$stateChange*` events will not work. You must use `$transitions.on*` hooks from now on.

You can read here.

https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/modules/ng1_state_events.html

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2720

Answer (score 1):

**$state** events are deprecated for angular version > 1.0.0. 
now onward for change event we have to use **$transitions**

refer [$transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43749120/4286411) from here