# How to use $transitions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router

Currently, I'm using:

- "angular-ui-router": "^0.4.2"
- "angular": "^1.6.3"
- "webpack": "^2.4.1"

I am aware of my current implementation might be [deprecated](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/ng1_state_events.html), just looking for the implementation(an example or documentation) of the new method. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Current implementation:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = angular
  .module('common', [
    'ui.router',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    require('./header').name,
    require('./sideBar').name,
    require('./footer').name
  ])
  .run(function($transitions, cfpLoadingBar) {
    $transitions.onStart({}, cfpLoadingBar.start);
    $transitions.onSuccess({}, cfpLoadingBar.complete);
  });
```

Current error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $transitionsProvider <- $transitions

Comment: Always specify injection manually using `$inject` or array notatian.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, wish it was easy as that. It's not the injection of the dependency.

Comment: Just mentioning it in case you didn't know.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> In new versions (>=1.0.0) the $state change events are deprecated, and now
>   you have to use the `$transitions` instead...

**$transitions for new versions (>= 1.0.0)** ([PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2PQuy7SnhOSTCwku6TLx?p=preview))

```
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$transitions'];

function MyCtrl($transitions) {
    $transitions.onSuccess({}, function($transition){
        console.log($transition.$from());
        console.log($transition.$to());
        console.log($transition.params());
    });
}
```

Available events ordered by invocation:

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function($transition){...});

$transitions.onExit({exiting: "stateName"}, function($transition){...});

$transitions.onRetain({}, function($transition){...});

$transitions.onEnter({entering: "stateName"}, function($transition){...});

$transitions.onFinish({}, function($transition){...});

$transitions.onSuccess({}, function($transition){...});
```

*Too see each event method in detail: [$transition service docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transitionservice.html)* 
*Also some examples: [Migrations examples from 0.4.2 to 1.0.0 in official docs](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events)*

---

**$state changes events for old versions (<= 0.4.2)** ([PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/OdGEKxzHmwDB4VuMc5e2?p=preview)):

```
MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {...});

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', 
        function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){...});
}
```

*Check [angular-ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events) for more $state change events*