# permission angularJS $routeChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make permission with `$routeChangeStart` in angular JS but it does't work. What I suppose to do is to make `$routeChangeStart` work with `$stateChangeSuccess`:

```js
angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope','$location', '$state', '$stateParams', 'loginService', 
  function($rootScope, $location, $state, $stateParams, loginService) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    var routespermission=['/'];
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){     
        alert('testing');
        console.log('>>exit tab: '+routespermission.index0f($location.path()));
        console.log('>>logged:' +loginService.islogged());
        if(routespermission.index0f($location.path()) !=-1 && !loginService.islogged()){
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        console.log('testing');
    });
    FastClick.attach(document.body);

  },
])
```

Comment: try using `$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition){...})`

Comment: `$routeChangeStart` is an `ngRoute` event. `$stateChangeSuccess` is a `UI-Router` event. Which are you using `ngRoute` or `UI-Router`?

Comment: UI-Router, i want make the code could using on the UI-Router what im suppose to do make it @georgeawg

Comment: may ur help me @AlekseySolovey  cause i have some project i can't resolve that, may I chat ur with personal, my be with email.. im really beginner with this

Answer (score 0):

> UI-Router, i want make the code could using on the UI-Router

Use `$stateChangeStart` instead of `$routeChangeStart`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state, $stateParams, loginService) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    var routespermission=['/'];
    ̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶o̶n̶(̶'̶$̶r̶o̶u̶t̶e̶C̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶S̶t̶a̶r̶t̶'̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶{̶ ̶
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(){     
        alert('testing');
        console.log('>>exit tab: '+routespermission.index0f($location.path()));
        console.log('>>logged:' +loginService.islogged());
        if(routespermission.index0f($location.path()) !=-1 && !loginService.islogged()){
            $location.path('/login');
        }
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        console.log('testing');
    });
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
})
```

For more information, see [UI-Router 0.3.1 Api Reference - $state](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

---

StateChange events have been deprecated for `ui.router >= 1.0`.

For more information, see [UI Router stateChangeSuccess event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992607/5535245).

Comment: im try like that, value from console is not came out... so i just try to get session form json session how bout that?